# Paper stock certificate for yahoo

Tags: stocks

This is a follow up question regarding ownership of paper stock certificate for yahoo. What do I do need to do with these certificates now that the deal with Verizon is completed and yahoo is now selling under ABBA?

Comment: I'd start by contacting Verizon's investor relations department (see http://www.verizon.com/about/investors/contact-investor-relations).

Answer (score 1):

[Computershare](https://www-us.computershare.com/Investor/Help) is the transfer agent for both [Yahoo and Verizon](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/nobody-wants-to-sell-their-zombie-yahoo-stock-back-to-altaba-2018-07-02):

> Beneficial holders: Most shareholders of Yahoo! hold their shares through a broker, bank or other nominee (that is, in “street name”) rather than directly in their own names. If you hold shares in street name, you are a “beneficial holder” of those shares, and the proxy materials, together with a PURPLE voting instruction form, will be forwarded to you by your broker, bank or other nominee.
>
> Shareholders of record: If you hold shares directly in your name with our transfer agent, Computershare Trust Company, N.A., you are considered the “shareholder of record” with respect to those shares, and the proxy materials, together with a PURPLE proxy card, have been sent directly to you by Yahoo!.

They should have contacted you, otherwise you should contact them for more information.

**References**

- [Preliminary Special Proxy Pertaining to a Sale](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1011006/000119312516706578/d206374dprem14a.htm)
- [Preliminary Proxy Statement](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1011006/000119312512191515/d319086dprec14a.htm)